# Error in Project setup in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-plugin

Error in pom.xml is **Missing artifact org.geppetto:model:jar:0.2.8**
But on the location that jar file is present.
[image: Error in pom.xml]

[image: Erro on build]

Comment: Can you post the rest of the error you are getting. It says "The following artifact..." but not sure the rest. However, that usually means there are either some dependencies missing or you need to add some new repositories.

Comment: Missing artifact org.geppetto:model:jar:0.2.8. I could not find it on mvn site also.

Comment: I would find the repo location and add it to your pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

There are two recommended solutions:

1. How did you obtain the dependency? Is it hosted in MVN Central or an internal dependency? If it is an internal dependency, make sure you install the dependency using Maven Install plugin.
   (Refer : http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/usage.html)
2. If you have already installed the dependency using the above step, then go to your local dependency location (.m2/org/gepetto/model) and delete all files ending with (.lastUpdated)

Comment: Yes i already followed 1 step and in .m2/org/gepetto/model directory there is only one file named 0.2.8